# Solution to ODE $D_t f(t)=\alpha c(t) f(t)$ subject to $f(0)=f(1)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the ordinary differential equation $$\left\{\begin{array}{c}D_t f(t)= \alpha c(t) f(t)\\ f(0)=f(1)\end{array}\right.$$ where $\alpha$ is a scalar. I guess the solution should be $$f(t)=e^{\alpha \int_0^t c(s)\ ds}+K\quad \quad (1)$$ but it seems I can't get $f(0)=f(1)$. Has the problem no solution or I'm going wrong when I suppose the solution must have the form $(1)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's do some intuition first: is $f(t)=0$ a solution? Yes, it is. But the solution you have written down as general does not include this. Next, if $f(t)$ is a solution, so is $Af(t)$, $t$ a constant. Therefore we expect $f(t)$ to have an overall arbitrary constant.

Rearranging the equation, we have
$$ f'(t)-\alpha c(t) f(t)=0 $$

An integrating factor is, as you suggest, $\exp{\left(-\alpha\int_0^t c(s)\, ds\right)}$, and so the solution is
$$ f(t) = A\exp{\left(-\alpha\int_0^t c(s)\, ds\right)}. $$
But then $f(0)=f(1)$, so
$$ A\left( \exp{\left(-\alpha\int_0^1 c(s)\, ds\right)}-1 \right) = 0, $$
so either $A=0$, or $\exp{\left(-\alpha\int_0^1 c(s)\, ds\right)}=1$, which occurs if and only if
$$ \alpha\int_0^1 c(s)\, ds =2k\pi i $$
for some integer $k$. In particular, if $c$ and $\alpha$ are real, then we must have $\int_0^1 c = 0$.

This is easy to believe: check the case $c(t)=1$. Then the solution is $f(t)=Ae^{\alpha t}$.

Answer (score 1):

You should be careful while exponentiating, the constant is multiplicative,
$$
f(t)=K·e^{\alpha \int_0^t c(s)\ ds}
$$
Evaluating at the boundary points gives
$$
f(0)=K·e^{\alpha \int_0^0 c(s)\ ds}=K
$$
and 
$$
f(1)=f(0)·e^{\alpha \int_0^1 c(s)\ ds}
$$
The condition is only satisfiable if
$$
\alpha \int_0^1 c(s)\ ds=0
$$

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand why I must suppose the solution is of the form $K\cdot e^{(..)}$ instead of $e^{(...)}+K$, can you explain it? It sounds we'd come to the same conclusion..

Comment: Probably you transformed to $\ln|f(t)|=C+α\int_0^tc(s)\,ds$. Addition in the exponent translates to multiplication of the exponentials, thus $K=\pm e^C$ or $K=0$.

Comment: Indeed, I solved using a wrong intuition but now it's clear, thanks.